# UITableViewCell orientation in iOS 8 not working

Tags: uitableview, ios8, autolayout

I have used iOS 8 with Autolayout but occur this bug when i try to change background image in UITableViewCell after orientation changed from Landscape to Portrait but after orientation happen still the tableviewcell didn't change the width for landscape mode ,this case happen only in iOS 8 but in iOS7 it was worked correctly

See the blew screenshot for this problem

Portrait

[image]

Landscape

[image]